# How to handle two click event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, click, dom-events

I want to do two click event in Javascript, 1 after another. First click code is working fine but the second click is not happening. For the second click, a window pops up after 0.5 seconds.

I am using the below code, I am new to JS and don't know what is the issue

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('artdeco-button--secondary');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ){
    x[i].addEventListener('click',function(){

        document.getElementsByClassName('ml1').click();
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you explain where the clicks should be occurring and also provide the html so that a user can debug if needed? I think with a little more editing you will have a very clear question that will get a great answer!

Comment: check whether `document.getElementsByClassName('ml1')` is returning an array or single element. maybe you still have to run a loop to click all the elements with class name `ml1`

Comment: It is on linkedin, where I need to click on "connect" then a pop appears with 2 more buttons "add note" or "send invite". First the code should click on "connect" then "send invite" with for loop

Answer (score 2):

You should use `dblclick` as event in `addEventListener` instead of `click`

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can do the same as follows
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.artdeco-button--secondary');

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // but here, you are trying to apply
    // an event to a list of Elements with getElementsByClassName
    // if you want to execute a click event to an specific element
    // you can do it as follows
    document.querySelector('#elementId').click();
    // or using the index of the element in an array
    const target = document.querySelectorAll('.target')[0];
    target.click();
    // or iterating the list to apply it to each element
    const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
    for (const target of targets) {
      target.click();
    }
  });
}
```